# save gitlab commit message to file

Tags: file, jenkins, gitlab, webhooks, git-commit

We had integrated Gitlab & Jenkins using Webhooks such that when ever code is pushed to git repo, automatically code base is built in Jenkins.

Is there someway, we can store commit messages to a file which can be used to generate release notes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the Jenkins job starts, it gets back the Git repo history before checking it out in its Jenkins agent workspace.

That means you can use the [Jenkins Git Changelog plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Changelog+Plugin) in order to use commit messages and generate (from a template) the release notes you need.